Faster Sequential Joins
In a regular Polars join where there are duplicates, the result is the cartesian product of the matched rows.
However, I would like to join the dataframes such that if there are duplicates, the rows are matched in a sequential manner.
Example below:
dfA = pl.from_repr('''
┌───────┬─────┐
│ group ┆ A   │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ X     ┆ 0   │
│ X     ┆ 1   │
│ Y     ┆ 2   │
│ Y     ┆ 3   │
└───────┴─────┘
''')

dfB = pl.from_repr('''
┌───────┬─────┐
│ group ┆ B   │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ X     ┆ 4   │
│ X     ┆ 5   │
│ Y     ┆ 6   │
│ Y     ┆ 7   │
└───────┴─────┘
''')

Current implementation: dfA.join(dfB, on='group')
┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ group ┆ A   ┆ B   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ X     ┆ 0   ┆ 4   │
│ X     ┆ 0   ┆ 5   │
│ X     ┆ 1   ┆ 4   │
│ X     ┆ 1   ┆ 5   │
│ Y     ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ Y     ┆ 2   ┆ 7   │
│ Y     ┆ 3   ┆ 6   │
│ Y     ┆ 3   ┆ 7   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘
Desired outcome: Sequential Left Join on 'group'
┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ group ┆ A   ┆ B   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ X     ┆ 0   ┆ 4   │
│ X     ┆ 1   ┆ 5   │
│ Y     ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ Y     ┆ 3   ┆ 7   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘

I'm not sure if there's already a term for such a join, so I have termed it a Sequential Join.
Currently, to achieve the desired outcome, I create an 'index' column on both dataframes then join on both the group and index.
(
    dfA
    .with_columns(
        index = pl.int_range(0, pl.len()).over('group')
    )
    .join(
        dfB
        .with_columns(
            index = pl.int_range(0, pl.len()).over('group')
        ),
        on = ['group', 'index']
    )
)

However, this can be very slow when joining on multiple columns or if there are many distinct groups.
For example, my main use case is for joining large time-series datasets with duplicated timestamps, so doing an pl.int_range(0, pl.len()).over('timestamp') can be very slow. Hence, I'm wondering if there is a faster or better way to do this.
Otherwise, is there a way to add custom join logic in Polars?

This assumes that the lengths of the groups match (the results are ill-defined otherwise anyway without further clarification):
pl.concat(
    [
        dfA.sort('group', maintain_order=True),
        dfB.sort('group', maintain_order=True).drop('group'),
    ],
    how="horizontal"
)


I don't think you can use join for that without adding row_number AKA index, but maybe you can adjust concat() with how = align and then explode():
(
    pl.concat([
        dfA.group_by("group").agg(pl.all()),
        dfB.group_by("group").agg(pl.all())
    ], how="align")
    .explode("A","B")
)

┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ group ┆ A   ┆ B   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ X     ┆ 0   ┆ 4   │
│ X     ┆ 1   ┆ 5   │
│ Y     ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ Y     ┆ 3   ┆ 7   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘

it works in your case right out of the box, but if lengths of the dfA and dfB are different, you would need to adjust resulting lists before explode.
Something like this (unfortunately, repeat_by() doesn't work with null so I had to use placeholder and replace it later):
(
    pl.concat([
        dfA.group_by("group").agg(pl.all()),
        dfB.group_by("group").agg(pl.all())
    ], how="align")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col(c).fill_null([]).list.concat(
            pl.lit(-1).repeat_by(
                pl.max_horizontal(pl.col("A","B").list.len()) - pl.col(c).list.len()
            )
        ) for c in ("A","B")
    )
    .explode("A","B")
    .with_columns(pl.col("A","B").replace(-1, None))
)


If the column is "sorted", the length of the group is the same as .rle()
dfA.select(pl.col("group").rle())

shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ group     │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {2,"X"}   │
│ {2,"Y"}   │
└───────────┘

Which can be given to .int_ranges() and .flatten()
dfA.with_columns(index = pl.int_ranges(pl.col("group").rle().struct[0]).flatten())

shape: (4, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ A   ┆ index │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ X     ┆ 0   ┆ 0     │
│ X     ┆ 1   ┆ 1     │
│ Y     ┆ 2   ┆ 0     │
│ Y     ┆ 3   ┆ 1     │
└───────┴─────┴───────┘

This seems to be faster operation. (Although it is probably dataset specific.)
